# SQL Server string parse

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

Can you help me extract date and text after reason code in the below text? I can use the `patindex` for date but problem is my date can be dd/mm/yyyy or d/m/yyyy

Project rescheduled to 03/02/2017 with reason code: customer related-customer will not be available

Project rescheduled to 2/3/2017 with reason code: weather inclement

I do not have permissions to create functions, it has to be a SQL query.

Thanks,
Anu

Answer (score 0):

You probably should add validation for input text to contain both 'with' and 'to' or filter 'invalid' entries out. But this is basically what you are asking for:

```
declare @s varchar(255)
set @s = 'Project rescheduled to 2/3/2017 with reason code : Weather Inclement'

select RIGHT(LEFT(@s, CHARINDEX(' with', @s)-1), CHARINDEX(' with', @s) -CHARINDEX('to', @s) - 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Project rescheduled to 03/02/2017 with reason code : Customer Related-Customer Will Not Be Available'),
(2,'Project rescheduled to 2/3/2017 with reason code : Weather Inclement')

Select A.ID
      ,Date   = try_convert(date,right(B.dP,len(B.dp)-charindex(' ',B.dP)),103)
      ,Reason = right(SomeCol,len(SomeCol)-charindex(':',SomeCol)-1)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select dP=substring(A.SomeCol,patindex('%/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',A.SomeCol)-6,11)
             ) B
```

Returns

```
ID  Date        Reason
1   2017-02-03  Customer Related-Customer Will Not Be Available
2   2017-03-02  Weather Inclement
```

Answer (score -1):

In SQL you cannot extract data that exist in the same column as an info. So if the info exits in the same column it cannot be extracted. Hence the info has to be in different tables in order to be extracted.